# API key error The variable "GOOGLE_MAPS_IOS_API_KEY" is not registered

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have a project which was created in Cordova and Ionic and should use the plugin cordova-plugin-googlemaps in version 2.6.2. I know that starting with version 2.6.0 of the GoogleMaps plugin in the config.xml file the API key of GoogleMaps has to be integrated as follows which I have:

```
<preference name = "GOOGLE_MAPS_ANDROID_API_KEY" value = "(api_key)" />
<preference name = "GOOGLE_MAPS_IOS_API_KEY" value = "(api_key)" />
```

So far I have only found the solution to regenerate the old API key which I did. I also included the old API key and generated a completely new one. I have no restrictions in it and also put a restriction. However I still get the error message

```
API key error
The variable "GOOGLE_MAPS_IOS_API_KEY" is not registered.
```

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="id_bundle" version="0.9.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>App_Name</name>
    <description>An awesome Ionic/Cordova app.</description>
    <author email="mail" href="URL">APP Developer Team</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://ionic.local/*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="20000" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="2000" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <icon height="1024" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
        <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" />
        <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" width="2732" />
        <preference name="TopActivityIndicator" value="whiteLarge" />
    </platform>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
    <engine name="android" spec="^7.1.1" />
    <engine name="ios" spec="4.5.5" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^2.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^5.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="^2.4.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="^2.2.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="^4.0.1">
        <variable name="GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value=" " />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-datepicker" spec="^0.9.3" />
    <plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="^1.11.1">
        <variable name="SENDER_ID" value="1234567890" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^1.2.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-globalization" spec="^1.11.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-android-support-gradle-release" spec="^1.4.4">
        <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION" value="27.+" />
    </plugin>
    <preference name="GOOGLE_MAPS_ANDROID_API_KEY" value="api_key" />
    <preference name="GOOGLE_MAPS_IOS_API_KEY" value="api_key" />
</widget>
```

**Cordova Plugin List**

```
cordova-android-support-gradle-release 1.4.4 "cordova-android-support-gradle-release"
cordova-plugin-datepicker 0.9.3 "DatePicker"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 4.0.1 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-globalization 1.11.0 "Globalization"
cordova-plugin-googlemaps 2.6.2 "cordova-plugin-googlemaps"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.2.1 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.2 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
cordova-sqlite-storage 3.2.0 "Cordova sqlite storage plugin - cordova-sqlite-storage plugin version"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
phonegap-plugin-push 1.11.1 "PushPlugin"
```

What can cause this error?

Answer (score 1):

Check how you declared the ids in `config.xml`.
This is the new format:

```
<widget>
  <preference name="GOOGLE_MAPS_ANDROID_API_KEY" value="(api key)" />
  <preference name="GOOGLE_MAPS_IOS_API_KEY" value="(api key)" />
</widget>
```

Answer (score 0):

same hare the map works fine but this message is annoying me

Comment: this solution worked for me : https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/you-need-to-declare-google-maps-android-api-key-in-config-xml/162120/2